# How to display one row from a HTML table and change to next?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a HTML table with 2 columns, 5 rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
function findMyRow(el)(){
    if(!el.parentNode) return null;
    else if(el.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase()=="tr") return el.parentNode;
    else return findMyRow(el.parentNode);
}
for(var i=0;i<tbl.rows.length;i++){
    tbl.rows[i].onclick = function(e){
        var selectedRow = null;
        if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()=="tr") selectedRow = e.target;
        selectedRow = findMyRow(e.target);
        //this is just for preventing false event raising
        if(!selectedRow) return false;
        var rowIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(tbl.rows, selectedRow);
        for(car j=0;j<selectedRow.cells.length;j++){
            var cell = selectedRow.cells[j];
            //let's say your inputs each has an unique ID based on your columns index
            //like <input id="cellData0" ttype="text" />
            //or <input id="cellData1" ttype="text" /> and so on
            document.getElementById("cellData" + j).value = cell.innerText;
        }
    }
}
```

although you can do this more easier than with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.rowIndex = 0; // gobal variable

    function displayRow(){
        var tableRows = $('#mytable tr');
        if(tableRows.length <= window.rowIndex) {
            window.rowIndex = 0;
        }
        var rowCells = $(tableRows[window.rowIndex]).find('td');
        $('.cellone').val($(rowCells[0]).html());
        $('.celltwo').val($(rowCells[1]).html());
        window.rowIndex = window.rowIndex + 1;
    };

    $('.next').click(function(event){ displayRow(); });
    displayRow();
});
```

There is a live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2qSnU/4/) Hope it helps!